# Gallery Filters, how to use in this example?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, gallery

Please have a look at Gallery in the following example?

https://w3layouts.com/preview/?l=/domicile-real-estate-category-flat-bootstrap-responsive-web-template/

I want to adapt this template for my website, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how the gallery filters works. There is no page reloading/php on clicking the filters, and none of the pictures have special tags.  If I rename the picture filename it no longer works, so it must use that somehow however I can't find the filenames listed in another file (JS, CSS).

Anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a bit of jQuery.

```js
$(function() {
  var selectedClass = "";
  $(".fil-cat").click(function(){ 
  selectedClass = $(this).attr("data-rel"); 
     $("#portfolio").fadeTo(100, 0.1);
  $("#portfolio div").not("."+selectedClass).fadeOut().removeClass('scale-anm');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("."+selectedClass).fadeIn().addClass('scale-anm');
      $("#portfolio").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }, 300); 
  
 });
});
```

```css
body{
  max-width: 900px;
  float: none;
  margin: auto; 
}
#portfolio {  
    margin: 1rem 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 3; 
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1rem;
    -moz-column-gap: 1rem;
    column-gap: 1rem;
    -webkit-column-width: 33.33333333333333%;
    -moz-column-width: 33.33333333333333%;
    column-width: 33.33333333333333%;
}
.tile { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease;
    transition: all 350ms ease;

}
.tile:hover { 

}

.scale-anm {
  transform: scale(1);
}


p{ 
  padding:10px; 
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc dotted; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-family: lato; 
  text-transform:uppercase; 
  font-size: 12px; 
  color: #333; 
  display:block; 
  float:left;
}

p:hover { 
  cursor:pointer; 
  background: #333; 
  color:#eee; }

.tile img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  
}

.btn {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #555;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: var(--darken-2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--darken-3);
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toolbar mb2 mt2">
  <button class="btn fil-cat" href="" data-rel="all">All</button>
  <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="web">Websites</button>
  <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="flyers">Flyers</button>
  <button class="btn fil-cat" data-rel="bcards">Business Cards</button>
</div> 
 
<div style="clear:both;"></div>   
<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
        <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/2-mon_1092-300x234.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/jti-icons_08-300x172.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/emi_haze-300x201.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
            <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/codystretch-300x270.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/jti-icons_08-300x172.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
    <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/transmission_01-300x300.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm flyers all">
           <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
        <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/the-ninetys-brand_02-300x300.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
            <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/15-dia_1092-1-300x300.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
       <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" /> 
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">
          <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/emi_haze-300x201.jpg" alt="" />  
  </div>
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
            <img src="http://demo.themerain.com/charm/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/transmission_01-300x300.jpg" alt="" />
  </div> 
  <div class="tile scale-anm web all">
      <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97190&w=350&h=190" alt="" />  
  </div> 
  <div class="tile scale-anm bcards all">     
            <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=19&txt=200%C3%97290&w=200&h=290" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Code Credits: [creotip](http://codepen.io/creotip)

Here are two codepens: [Codepen 1](http://codepen.io/creotip/pen/dfjeF) - [Codepen 2](http://codepen.io/echodean/pen/LEzKF)

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough solution. I will use this if I can't figure out how the template does it. Do you happen to know how this works in the template? Because I think it must use something else.. I don't see different tags by each picture..